# IIS Windows Authentication: The (SAMAccountName=) search filter is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-authentication

I am deploying a project to a Windows Web Server 2008 but the project is receiving the following error msg:  **Error in MyApps; method MyApp.Page_Load.  Exception is: System.ArgumentException: The (SAMAccountName=) search filter is invalid.**

In the **system.web** section of the web.config is **authentication mode="Windows".**  The application is failing when it is trying to grab the username from AD using:  **strUser = Context.User.Identity.Name**.

IIS is configured with Windows Authentication enabled and all other modes of authentication are disabled.

Not sure what else you might need -- your help would be appreciated!

Comment: You configured Active Directory on server or are you using Active Directory Application Mode (ADAM)? I guess that ADAM do not have SAMAccountName property.

Comment: Active Directory is on a server

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't understand why this solved the problem -- but it did.  One of my co-workers removed the binding to a specific IP address in the pool of IP addresses for the web server and just bound the web site to a unique port number.

As far as I know this hasn't been a problem in the past -- perhaps it has something to do with Windows Authentication.  I would love to hear comments from the community on why this worked.

**Thanks to the folks who provided suggestions**.  Stack Overflow is a wonderful community.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not configured corresponding security service in you server WebServer role. You probably missing "Windows Authentication" service.

Server Manager -> Roles -> Web Server -> Add Role Services. In the opened wizard select "Windows Authentication" under "Security" and proceeed to installation

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner on IIS ... How do I set the security service?

Comment: Windows authentication already is listed as installed under the Security section.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Aside from being a Windows auth issue, you will get this error if you send an empty string for the username (we had invalid test data)